# Disappearance of my character due collision. pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame, character, collision

I have this problem since the first time i tried to do a code my problem is with the collision system that is inside this class.

```
def updates(self, wall):
        self.hero = hero
        self.wall = wall
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        list_of_collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.wall, False)
        for wall in list_of_collision:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                self.rect.right = pared.rect.left

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        list_of_collision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.wall, False)
        for block in list_of_collision:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
```

FOr some extrange reason my character collide perfectly with one wall, but disappears in the others.I tried to solve it myself, i wouldn't be asking if i havent tried everything i thought of.

This is the complete code (Sorry is somehow long)

```
#imports 
import pygame
import random

#colors and images
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#Class and fuctions
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, high, width):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([high, width])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Prota(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 450
        self.rect.y = 300
    def velocity(self, x, y):
            self.rect.x += x
            self.rect.y += y    
    def update(self, wall):
        self.hero = hero
        self.wall = wall
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        list_of_collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.wall, False)
        for wall in list_of_collisions:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        list_of_collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.wall, False)
        for block in list_of_collisions:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right


#creating room
dimensions = [900, 600]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions)
pygame.display.set_caption("The oblivion of the voices")

#variables
    #walls
list_walls= pygame.sprite.Group()
wallr = Wall(850, 0, 50, 600)
walll = Wall(0, 0, 50, 600)
walltop = Wall(0, 0, 900, 50)
wallbot = Wall(0, 550, 900, 50)
lista_paredes.add(paredd,paredi, paredar, paredab)


 #protagonist
hero = pygame.sprite.Group()
Aaron = Prota()
hero.add(Aaron)

    #list of everything
list_of_lists = pygame.sprite.Group()
list_of_lists.add(walll, wallr, walltop, wallbot, Aaron)





#creating a clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#initializing pygame
pygame.init()

#The game start
done = False


#-------------------------------------------------- HERE IS WHERE THE GOOD STUFF IS------------------------------
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
#LOGIC OF THE GAME
    #keyboard for moving charac
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Aaron.velocity (-10, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Aaron.velocity (10, 0)
                print(Aaron.cambio_x, Aaron.rect.x)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                Aaron.velocity (0, 10)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                Aaron.velocity (0, -10)
    x = Aaron.rect.y
    y = Aaron.rect.x
    cam_x = Aaron.change_x
    cam_y = Aaron.change_y
    print("[",x,"*",y,"-","]", "[" ,cam_x,"^", cam_y,"&","]")
    Aaron.update(list_walls)


    #mouse for touching ( not in used yet)
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    royx = pos[0]
    royy = pos[1]




#Draw
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    list_of_lists.draw(screen)

 #FInal ditails
    clock.tick(20)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

If you noticed, i tried to print also the variables, x, y, cam_x, cam_y and this is what the console shows. The values  0, 200 just happens when i press the right button.

```
[ 300 * 200 - ] [ 0 ^ 0 & ]
[ 300 * 150 - ] [ 0 ^ 0 & ]
[ 300 * 150 - ] [ 0 ^ 0 & ]
[ 300 * 150 - ] [ 0 ^ 0 & ]
[ 300 * 150 - ] [ 0 ^ 0 & ]
0 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from this

```
for block in list_of_collision:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
```

to this

```
for block in list_of_collision:
                if self.change_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                elif :
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
```

you're setting the the right and left of your box, when you should be setting the top and bottom

Comment: <Yeah, sorry for that. Last time> And what you recommend me to do?

Comment: one of the if statements need to check if it is also equal to zero. You need to decide which one that is, it usually doesn't matter. <http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/comparison_operators_example.htm> Here is a list of comparison operators, i suggest you use either <= or >=
This may not fix it, but is good practice none-the-less to make sure  your if else statements encompass the entire range of numbers when necessary

Comment: Also, one more thing im noticing is that when you're checking the `if self.cambio_y > 0:`, you are setting the left and right positions of the rectangle instead of the top and bottom, so the rectangle may be, in a sense, teleporting itself to the far sides of your top wall to where you cant see it

Comment: THat is exactly what is happening.I traduce the code to english to better understanding. The list you give me show an error.

Comment: Update: i fix the mistakes you state in the way you said but still my character keep dissapearing.Now in every side.

Comment: Well i apologize, then. I can't be of any help to you. I would suggest trying to translate some of your variable names, it might help find an answer here

Comment: I did it,because i knew it was confusing. If you can't help me is okay; thanks for trying anyways.

Comment: Can you explain what change_x is for? Also, why are you looping 5 times when you change velocity?

Comment: Wow, i didn't notice that i was looping in velocity. Change_x started as an experiment of some colision system i was trying to create myself but fail miserabily. Now is just some variable i use to gather information and thinkering without damage the basic structure of the program.But the basic idea is unknown for me, i still can't comprehend collision system very well so i copy this part of the code from another source and still don't know exactly what change_x or change_y are doing in the if statement inside update.

Comment: That might be your problem. Since you've modified change_x from its original intention, it's difficult to know exactly what its doing. In the collision, it's checking change_x and modifying your rect.left to be equal to the walls rect.right, or vice versa. This means that when it collidies, it's collision reaction is to make sure the walls stay touching and go no further, but without sticking them together, so thats why your code doesnt account for zero probably. Ignore my first change, ive edited the answer to reflect a new change

Comment: No, the original code is still there.                                      http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=move_with_walls_example.py

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood again. Look at the code block again. you were setting your left and right instead of your top and bottom when checking change_y. You should also make sure your collision code looks exactly like his

Comment: Ok, i follow you advice with actually all the code. Everything pretty and neat until this happened.    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/Escritorio/Codigo python/The_oblivion.py", line 143, in <module>
    list_of_lists.update()
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: That is an entirely different problem lol. Look over his code some more and see if you can figure it out. If you haven't found the answer in a day or so, ask another specific question :)

Comment: YOu were right, i follow the code wrongly and that is why it did not work. NOw is working perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.